# trying to display filtered result from local storage in todo app but stuck on it

Tags: javascript

This is my first attempt at learning to work with local storage. I am trying to filter the tasks by category. So far I am able to get the tasks category-wise in console but stuck on how to display them on app. i am stuck on this, need help in understanding this.
Attaching the javascript and HTML code.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];
    // todosBf = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todosBF')) || [];
    const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
    const newTodoForm = document.querySelector('#new-todo-form');

    const username = localStorage.getItem('username') || '';
    
    nameInput.value = username;

    nameInput.addEventListener('change', e => {
        localStorage.setItem('username', e.target.value);
    })

    newTodoForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const todo = {
            content: e.target.elements.content.value,
            category: e.target.elements.category.value,
            done: false,
            createdAt: new Date().getTime()
        }

        const textWarning = document.querySelector('#text-warning');
        const categoryWarning = document.querySelector('#category-warning');

        if (todo.content == "") {
            textWarning.classList.add('warning')
        } else {
            if (todo.category == "") {
                categoryWarning.classList.add('warning')    
            } else {
                categoryWarning.classList.remove('warning')

                todos.push(todo);

                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
            
                e.target.reset();

                displayTodos();
            }
        }
    })
    displayTodos();
});

function displayTodos() {
    const todoList = document.querySelector('#todo-list');
    const businessFilter = document.querySelector('#business-filter');
    const personalFilter = document.querySelector('#personal-filter');
    const allFilter = document.querySelector('#all-filter');
    
    todoList.innerHTML = '';

    todos.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt).forEach(todo => {
        const todoItem = document.createElement('div');
        todoItem.classList.add('todo-item');

        const label = document.createElement('label');
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        const content = document.createElement('div');
        const actions = document.createElement('div');
        const edit = document.createElement('button');
        const deleteButton  = document.createElement('button');

        input.type = 'checkbox';
        input.checked = todo.done;
        span.classList.add('bubble');

        if (todo.category == 'personal') {
            span.classList.add('personal');
        } else {
            span.classList.add('business');
        }

        content.classList.add('todo-content');
        actions.classList.add('actions');
        edit.classList.add('edit');
        deleteButton.classList.add('delete');

        content.innerHTML = `<input type="text" value="${todo.content}" readonly>`;

        edit.innerHTML = 'Edit';
        deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';

        label.appendChild(input);
        label.appendChild(span);
        actions.appendChild(edit);
        actions.appendChild(deleteButton);
        todoItem.appendChild(label);
        todoItem.appendChild(content);
        todoItem.appendChild(actions);

        todoList.appendChild(todoItem);

        if (todo.done) {
            todoItem.classList.add('done');
        }

        input.addEventListener('click', e => {
            todo.done = e.target.checked;
            localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));

            if (todo.done) {
                todoItem.classList.add('done');
            } else {
                todoItem.classList.remove('done');
            }
            displayTodos();
        })

        edit.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const input = content.querySelector('input');
            input.removeAttribute('readonly');
            input.focus();
            input.addEventListener('blur', e => {
                input.setAttribute('readonly', true);
                todo.content = e.target.value;
                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
                displayTodos();
            })
        })

        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
            todos = todos.filter(t => t != todo);
            localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
            displayTodos();
        })
    });

    businessFilter.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // todosBF = todos.filter( todo => todo.category == 'business');
        // localStorage.setItem('todosBF', JSON.stringify(todosBF));
        
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')).filter( t => t.category == 'business'); 
    });
};
```

```css
:root {
  --primary: #EA40A4;
  --business: #3A82EE;
  --personal: var(--primary);
  --light: #EEE;
  --grey: #888;
  --dark: #313154;
  --danger: #ff5b57;

  --shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --business-glow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(58, 130, 238, 0.75);
  --personal-glow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(234, 64, 164, 0.75);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
}

input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]), button {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: initial;
}

body {
  background: var(--light);
  color: var(--dark);
}

section {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

h3 {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

h4 {
  color: var(--grey);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.greeting .title {
 display: flex;
}

.greeting .title input{
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.greeting .title,
.greeting .title input {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.create-todo input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--dark);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow); 
  margin-bottom:  1.5rem;
}

.create-todo .options {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.create-todo .options label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.bubble {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid var(--business);
  box-shadow: var(--business-glow);
}

.bubble.personal {
  border-color: var(--personal);
  box-shadow: var(--personal-glow);
}

.bubble::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: var(--business);
  box-shadow: var(--business-glow);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.bubble.personal::after {
  background-color: var(--personal);
  box-shadow: var(--personal-glow);
}

input:checked ~ .bubble::after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;  
}

.create-todo .options label div {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.create-todo input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.create-todo input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.todo-list .todo-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.todo-item label {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-item .todo-content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.todo-item .todo-content input {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.todo-item .actions {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item .actions button {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.todo-item .actions button:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.todo-item .actions .edit {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background-color: var(--primary);
}

.todo-item .actions .delete {
  background-color: var(--danger);
}

.todo-item.done .todo-content input {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: var(--grey);
}

.empty-warning {
  color: red;
  opacity: 70%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.category-warning {
  color: red;
  opacity: 70%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.warning {
  display: block;
}

.filter-feature input[type="button"] {
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;0,900;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
        <title>TODO List App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="app">

            <section class="greeting">
                <h2 class="title">
                    What's up, <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name Here">
                </h2>
            </section>

            <section class="create-todo">
                <h3>Create a TODO</h3>

                <form id="new-todo-form">
                    <h4>What's on your todo list?</h4>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="content"
                        id="content"
                        placeholder="e.g. make a video" />
                        <h4 class="empty-warning" id="text-warning">Please Enter Something</h4>
                        <h4>Pick a category</h4>
                        <div class="options">

                            <label>
                                <input
                                type="radio"
                                name="category"
                                id="category1"
                                value="business" />
                                <span class="bubble business"></span>
                                <div>Business</div>
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <input
                                type="radio"
                                name="category"
                                id="category2"
                                value="personal" />
                                <span class="bubble personal"></span>
                                <div>Personal</div>
                            </label>

                        </div>
                        <h4 class="category-warning" id="category-warning">Select a category for your TODO</h4>

                        <input type="submit" value="Add todo">
                </form>
            </section>

            <section class="todo-list">
                <h3>TODO LIST</h3>
                
                <div class="filter-feature" id="filter-feature">
                    <h3 class="filter-title">
                        Filter by:
                        <input type="button" value="All" id="all-filter">
                        <input type="button" value="Business" id="business-filter">
                        <input type="button" value="Personal" id="personal-filter">
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="list" id="todo-list">

                    <!-- <div class="todo-item">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            <span class="bubble business"></span>
                        </label>

                        <div class="todo-content">
                            <input type="text" value="Make a video" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="actions">
                            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="todo-item">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            <span class="bubble personal"></span>
                        </label>

                        <div class="todo-content">
                            <input type="text" value="Get milk" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="actions">
                            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> -->
                    
                </div>
            </section>

        </main>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please use a code snippet so that we can see what the code outputs? You can do this by clicking the button next to the image button when editing the question.

Comment: @nd03 I attached the snippet in the post. It's showing some unexpected error here but working fine on my system within vscode. if you can have a look at it please, i would really appreciate that?